# Why does my for loop not loop the number of times I specified?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have been trying to write a program in C but I don't know if it's correct because my `for` loop at the start ends after only 3 loops when it should end after 10.  If someone could tell me where the issue is, I would appreciate it. Here is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int array[size],sum[size],k,sum1,i,j;
    sum1=0;

    printf("give 10 integers:\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        scanf("%d", array[i]);
        sum[i]=0;
        }
    
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
       {
        for(j=10; j>i; j--){
            if(array[j-1]>array[j]){
                k=array[j-1];
                array[j-1]=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j-1];

            }
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<size; i++){
            if(array[i]=array[i+1])
            sum[i]=sum[i]+1;
            }
    for(i=1; i<size; i++){
            sum1=sum1+sum[i];
            }

 printf("%d", sum1);
}
```

I've tried deleting the other loops but then the for loops only once.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to find your logic error. If you don't know how to use a debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. There is no more powerful tool in a programmer's toolbox than a debugger, and it's never too early to learn how to start using one.

Comment: Side note: you have `printf("give 10 integers:\n");` — you should use `printf("give %d elements:\n", size);` so that if you change the value of `size`, the prompt remains accurate.  Not a part of your current problem, though.  (You should also include a newline at the end of the format string for the final `printf()`.

Comment: You have problems in your 'swap' logic: `if (array[j-1] > array[j]) { k = array[j-1]; array[j-1] = array[j]; array[j] = array[j-1]; }`.  You don't always use `j - 1`instead of `j`.  That leads to writing out of bounds of your array, probably trampling over your loop control variables and causing the loop to terminate before you expected it to.  ——— You also have a problem (which your compiler should be complaining about) with `scanf("%d", array[i]);` — you need `scanf("%d", &array[i]);` to pass the address of the array element to `scanf()`.  And that probably does cause the crash!

Answer (score 1):

Invalid scanf 2nd argument:

```c
scanf("%d", array[i]);
```

array[i] is an integer, scanf requires a pointer, so:

```c
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
// or
scanf("%d", array + i);
```

Affectation in condition:

```c
if (array[i] = array[i+1])
```

Should be

```c
if (array[i] == array[i+1])
```

Variable k is set, but never used.

Array 'sum' can be filled with 0s at declaration.

```c
int sum[size] = { 0 };
```

Iterating array from index 1, instead of 0.

Index 'j' is initialized with 10, while max index is 9.

Setting a variable to itself, did you mean to swap the variables using 'k'?

```c
array[j - 1] = array[j]; // both cells now have same value
array[j] = array[j - 1]; // so this means array[j] = array[j]
```

Improved the code a bit, but can't name other loops, I don't know what you were trying to achieve.
Code compiles without error, only semantic errors are left.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBERS_COUNT 10

static void promptNumbers(int numbers[], int numbersCount)
{
    int readNumbers;

    printf("Give %d integers:\n", numbersCount);

    for (readNumbers = 0; readNumbers < numbersCount; readNumbers++)
        scanf("%d", numbers + readNumbers);
}

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[NUMBERS_COUNT];
    int sum[NUMBERS_COUNT] = { 0 };
    int i, j, sum1;

    sum1 = 0;

    promptNumbers(numbers, NUMBERS_COUNT);

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        for (j = 9; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j])
            {
                numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_COUNT - 1; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
            sum[i] = sum[i] + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_COUNT; i++)
        sum1 = sum1 + sum[i];

    printf("%d", sum1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c -o temp
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10' | ./temp
```

EDIT: 2nd iteration, still unclear what you're doing with the array 'sum', counting how many duplicates you have ?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBERS_COUNT 10

static void promptNumbers(int numbers[], int numbersCount)
{
    int readNumbers;

    printf("Give %d integers:\n", numbersCount);

    for (readNumbers = 0; readNumbers < numbersCount; readNumbers++)
        scanf("%d", numbers + readNumbers);
}

static void swapNumbers(int * const first, int * const second)
{
    int swapBuffer = * first;
    * first = * second;
    * second = swapBuffer;
}

static void sortNumbers(int numbers[], int numbersCount)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++)
    {
        for (j = 9; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j])
                swapNumbers(& numbers[j], & numbers[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[NUMBERS_COUNT];
    int sum[NUMBERS_COUNT] = { 0 };
    int i, sum1;

    sum1 = 0;

    promptNumbers(numbers, NUMBERS_COUNT);
    sortNumbers(numbers, NUMBERS_COUNT);

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
            sum[i] = sum[i] + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBERS_COUNT; i++)
        sum1 = sum1 + sum[i];

    printf("%d", sum1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c -o temp
echo '10 2 3 7 1 1 8 8 8 8' | ./temp
echo '10 2 3 7 4 1 9 6 5 8' | ./temp
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your loop has to start from 0. Use:

```c
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ...
}
```

See, the loop will begin with `i = 0` and will keep running so long as `i < size`. When `i` is *exactly equal* to `size`, it will not run anymore.

To get an idea of this, run the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, size = 10;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("The value of i is: %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will show you that the loop never runs for `i = 10`, since when `i` is `10` then `i < size` is False, so the loop condition is false.

Comment: I'm not clear how this addresses the problem — why does the loop in the question stop after 3 iterations?